# Retrieve Currency Symbol from curency code

Tags: java

In one of my application web service call is used which returns more than 20 currencies e.g

USD, JPY, INR, GBP, ESP, EGP etc.

Now i need to convert each and every currencies into the related symbol. Please suggest how can i implement the same in my application.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: IMO, that question doesn't deserve a WHYT.

Comment: @sp00m I spent 10 minutes trying to decipher what `WHYT` means in this context, but in vain.

Comment: @adarshr I had the same problem and wanted to comment too, but then when I typed it I suddenly saw it: What Have You Tried

Comment: Sorry, my french abbreviations addiction is killing me.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Currency.getInstance("GBP").getSymbol();
```

It prints `£` for me.

But it may not print values for INR, ESP etc. Using a custom map approach is better.

Comment: is it dependent of java version, since its not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I would use;

- a map like `Map<Current, String>`
- have your own enum type for Currency which has this hard coded
- use a Properties loaded from disk

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Currency object's getSymbol method.

What symbol is used depends on the Locale which is used See this and this.

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("lv","LV"));
Currency c  = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
System.out.println(c.getSymbol());
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a hashmap, where the name (USD, JPY, ...) is the key and the symbol ($, €, ...) is the value.

Comment: Hi All, I used one property file and then i put all the currencies and the related Unicode characters as key & value and once i received the currency from the WebService Call i picked up the related Unicode value which is mapped in the property file.